# Creating a usable index in PouchDB with pouchdb-find

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I'm having a bit of trouble creating an index to search in pouchDB using [pouchdb-find](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find). I keep getting the error `couldn't find a usable index. try creating an index on: dateCreated. Make sure that only $eq, $gt, $gte, $lt, and $lte are used for the indexed fields.` - but I'm not entirely sure what that means or how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
PouchDB.debug.enable('pouchdb:find');

var testDB = new PouchDB('testDB');

testDB.destroy('testDB').then(function () {
    testDB = new PouchDB('testDB');
}).then(function () {
    return testDB.bulkDocs([
      {siteTitle : 'Google Search', dateCreated: (~~(Math.random() * 100000) + 1), domain: 'google.com',  _id: 'doc1'},
      {siteTitle : 'Google Mail', dateCreated: (~~(Math.random() * 100000) + 1), domain: 'google.com',  _id: 'doc2'},
      {siteTitle : 'Yahoo Search', dateCreated: (~~(Math.random() * 100000) + 1), domain: 'yahoo.com',  _id: 'doc3'},
      {siteTitle : 'Bing Search', dateCreated: (~~(Math.random() * 100000) + 1), domain: 'bing.com',  _id: 'doc4'},
      {siteTitle : 'Baidu Search', dateCreated: (~~(Math.random() * 100000) + 1), domain: 'baidu.com',  _id: 'doc5'},
      {siteTitle : 'Hacker News', dateCreated: (~~(Math.random() * 100000) + 1), domain: 'ycombinator.com',  _id: 'doc6'},
      {siteTitle : 'Mozilla foo', dateCreated: (~~(Math.random() * 100000) + 1), domain: 'mozilla.org',  _id: 'doc7'},
      {siteTitle : 'Android foo', dateCreated: (~~(Math.random() * 100000) + 1), domain: 'android.com',  _id: 'doc8'},
      {siteTitle : 'Wikipedia foo', dateCreated: (~~(Math.random() * 100000) + 1), domain: 'wikipedia.org',  _id: 'doc9'},
      {siteTitle : 'Twitter foo', dateCreated: (~~(Math.random() * 100000) + 1), domain: 'twitter.com',  _id: 'doc10'},
      {siteTitle : 'Facebook foo', dateCreated: (~~(Math.random() * 100000) + 1), domain: 'facebook.com',  _id: 'doc11'},
      {siteTitle : 'Reddit foo', dateCreated: (~~(Math.random() * 100000) + 1), domain: 'reddit.com',  _id: 'doc12'},
      {siteTitle : 'The Verge foo', dateCreated: (~~(Math.random() * 100000) + 1), domain: 'theverge.com',  _id: 'doc13'},
      {siteTitle : 'Dropbox foo', dateCreated: (~~(Math.random() * 100000) + 1), domain: 'dropbox.com',  _id: 'doc14'},
      {siteTitle : 'Microsoft foo', dateCreated: (~~(Math.random() * 100000) + 1), domain: 'microsoft.com',  _id: 'doc15'}
    ]);
}).then(function () {
    return testDB.createIndex({
        index: {
          fields: ['dateCreated', 'domain'],
          name: 'indexFoo'
        }
    });

}).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
}).then(function(){
    return testDB.getIndexes();
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}).then(function(result){
  return testDB.find({
    selector: {
      dateCreated: {'$exists': true}
    },
    use_index: 'indexFoo',
    sort: [{dateCreated: 'desc'}]
  });
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  console.log(err.message);
});
```

And here is a live version: https://jsbin.com/qimulecezi/8/edit?js,console

As far as I can tell I'm creating the index the same way it's shown here: https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find#dbcreateindexindex--callback
and my use of find with sort is pretty much verbatim: https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find#sorting

Answer (score 2):

I thought I should post the answer here as I found it somewhere else.

[nolanlawson](https://github.com/nolanlawson) answered my question on irc, he said:

> $exists doesn't do what you think it does
>
> You want $gt: null instead. Sorry it's confusing. I didn't design the API

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same error "unusable index" in PouchDB.

In my case, I created the index, then ran db.find() and it hit that error.

To resolve this, I changed my code to run a search, and from the index call back call another method to perform the find.

```
  function search() {

      var tmp = new Date().toISOString();
      //console.log('new Date() ' + tmp);

      db.createIndex({
          index: {
              fields: ['title']
          }
      }).then(function (result) {
          console.log('createIndex ' + result);

          findIt(); // Run Find
      }).catch(function (err) {
          console.log('createIndex ' + err);
      });
  } 

function findIt()
  {
      db.find({
          selector: { title: { $eq: 'ABC2' } },
          sort: ['title']
          //,      use_index: 'indexFoo'
      }).then(function (result) {      
          //console.log('find - result ' + result);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

         // console.log('JSON' + JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2));

          console.log('Title: ' + result.docs[0].title);

      }).catch(function (err) {
          console.log('find - err ' + err);
      });
  }
```